# Adjusting padding value with respect browser height

Tags: html, css, browser

I'm looking for a way to adjust the value of button element's padding with respect to the height of the browser window - not the width. The value on `padding` should adjust relative to the browser window height. Is there a way I can achieve this with CSS?

```css
.btn {
  padding: 4%;
}
```

```html
<div class="position">
  <button class="btn bg-primary btn-lg">PLAY</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button class="btn bg-primary btn-lg">SIGN IN</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button class="btn btn-lg bg-primary">SETTINGS</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button class="btn bg-primary btn-lg">ABOUT</button>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the `vh` *viewport height* unit, where `1vh` represents *1/100th* of the *viewport height*:

```css
.btn {
  padding: 5vh 10vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="position">
  <button class="btn bg-primary btn-lg">PLAY</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button class="btn bg-primary btn-lg">SIGN IN</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button class="btn btn-lg bg-primary">SETTINGS</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button class="btn bg-primary btn-lg">ABOUT</button>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As you are using bootstrap CSS framework, it has a class "btn" with padding property.

So, to override it you can use !important rule.

.btn {
padding: 4% !important;
}

Comment: I want to override it with a value with respect to the browsers height.